# Typescript failed to infer generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm playing with the following snippet. When I remove the line `validate: (...) => {}`, `A` is correctly inferred as `rule1: { v: number }`. However, when the line is not removed, `A` is inferred as `unknown`. Any ideas what causes this and how to fix it? Thanks in advance :)

```
type Arguments<A> = {
  [K in keyof A]: {
        args: {
          [K1 in keyof A[K]]: {
              assert?: (arg: unknown) => arg is A[K][K1];
          }
        };
        validate?: (value: unknown, args: A[K]) => unknown;
  }
}

function test<A>(args: Arguments<A>) {}

test({
    rule1: {
        args: {
            v: {
                assert: (arg): arg is number => typeof arg === 'number',
            }
        },
        validate: (value, args) => {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I really confuse, can you give me any insight what do you wanna achieve here. What is a purpose here?

Comment: Test is a function that accepts a config object to produce some sort of validator (in this case the validator name is rule1). This validator may need an argument v which has to be a number. It will be checked and passed to the validate method. I want the method to be able to access the types the arguments. @MaciejSikora

Comment: This is a design limitation of TS, I think... see [#12621](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12621) or [#26418](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26418).  Would you be open to a workaround that uses currying or multiple function arguments?

Comment: @jcalz Sure why not?

Comment: Multiple arguments: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgIID4AUAsAFCJmICGATgOZoBciA3ogNoDSiMSA1igJ5xgibAF1GLDgEYuvAUJEdR45iXLrKaNCipQA-I3zUajcDzBwA7mACUiALy5KtLmkXtR00QG415AL6Igf4ANH5kAG4UADYwACYUqAbMbJzciHyCwmKGUdEgKKZg5lZgIc50jNhKdo6IZhbWQSR2LP4kJKgYRKTkTOEaVCDRKFISAxrkEeO9k3Oa2rqGxjaMxq6IYCAAtgBGOg5OUPwADigK6-ZXiADkW3s6N2Gz880v6u0voQP97+RDIzGEzm+DyBXKxjQtScbQGnxs3iAA)

Comment: currying: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwK4FsIDtgGcA8MB8UAvFAN4CwAUFDVANoDSUAlulANYQgD2AZrAF0AXGSq1xUAIaIsIitQmLGARhZtOPfjEYDhohYsNSsWCHGAB+EQAppCEUnTt03AO7oAlMUJ2WWWDoqAgDcYka0AL5hihGhBhIAbpIANswAJpLAEFZQ1knJSBAOTi7uADRSMiLaDAJeRISOzm7oceJRlB1UAMbc6FjAlQjEULyO3cDMfVA4ACr41tFDsmT0TKwcXHxQs3ryRpImZpY2dsXN7vU+iH47Om2RUBFlS-npmdk2+YXnpegVdhWsyuUCafyoXn2tDgEGASDgbGspGWFTeGSyTw8cS6lCoY3QEymbCyAzwC0B1UQqAw2DJkKeVCoJOASKWcCQyQgyhEdlZ8XECTkSwOR3Mp0QHh5N2Y-nQqAARmZvFBQJBtr4iJqoAByOUoRVwbUvfmRJbPXLfCAAmQg5EdcQeKgRLFAA)

Comment: If either or both of those are useful to you let me know and I'll write up an answer

Comment: @jcalz Ah crap can't do that, it breaks the API. However, it's very interesting and i would like to see an answer

Comment: Are you sure the currying answer breaks the API?  It is mostly an inference helper to allow you to use your original function

Comment: @jcalz Oops my bad, didn't read it thoroughly enough. Currying looks good

Comment: @jcalz I was looking at the currying method. Am I right that i need to separate args and validate into 2 separator arguments instead of an option argument? Because when i did that it is inferred as unknown again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the compiler needs to both infer the generic type parameter *and* the type of the unannotated callback parameter, inside the same object, and it can't really do that consistently.  This is a known design limitation; see [microsoft/TypeScript#12621](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12621) and [microsoft/TypeScript#26418](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26418) among others.  The short answer here is you either have to give up on one of these inferences (by either manually specifying the generic type parameter or by manually annotating the callback parameters), *or* you have to break the single object apart into multiple objects so that the compiler can do the multiple inference passes in stages.

The workaround I'll present here is a helper function which builds your single object from two separate ones.  The first object will be used to infer the generic type parameter, which will then be used in the contextual type of the callback parameter in the second object.  (I called this "currying" in the comments but it really isn't currying, sorry about the terminology error)

```
const arg = function <T>(
    args: { [K in keyof T]: {
        assert?: (arg: unknown) => arg is T[K];
    } },
    validate?: (value: unknown, args: T) => unknown
) {
    return ({ args, validate });
}
```

The `arg()` function takes two parameters, `args` and `validate`, and combines them into a single object.  When you call `test()`, now, you use `arg()` to build each property:

```
test({
    rule1: arg({
        v: {
            assert: (arg): arg is number => typeof arg === 'number',
        }
    }, (value, args) => { }
    )
});
```

Here the type parameter in `arg()` is inferred to be `{v: number}`, and thus the type parameter in `test()` is now properly inferred to be `{rule1: {v: number}}` as desired.  It's not perfect, but it's the best I can think of for now.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwK4FsIDtgGcA8MB8UAvFAN4CwAUFDVANoDSUAlulANYQgD2AZrAF0AXGSq1xUAIaIsIitQmLGARhZtOPfjEYDhohYsNSsWCHGAB+EQAppCEUnTt03AO7oAlMUJ2WWWDoqAgDcYka0AL5hihGhBhIAbpIANswAJpLAEFZQ1knJSBAOTi7uADRSMiLaDAJeRISOzm7oceJRlB1UAMbc6FjAlQjEULyO3cDMfVA4ACr41tFDsmT0TKwcXHxQs3ryRpImZpY2dsXN7vU+iH47Om2RUBFlS-npmdk2+YXnpegVdhWsyuUCafyoXn2tDgEGASDgbGspGWFTeGSyTw8cS6lCoY3QEymbCyAzwC0B1UQqAw2DJkKeVCoJOASKWcCQyQgyhEdlZ8XECTkSwOR3Mp0QHh5N2Y-nQqAARmZvFBQJBtr4iJqoAByOUoRVwbUvfmRJbPXLfCAAmQg5EdcQeKgRLFAA)

Comment: Very useful and well explained. Would be nice if you could answer my last question in the comment above :)